# second maximum number among three numbers without using if else or ternary operator. using max and min function

Tags: java, arrays

```
void cal(int a,int b,int c)
 {
        int x=Math.max(a,b);
        int y=Math.max(b,c);
        int z=Math.max(a,c);
        int z1=Math.max(x,y);
        int z2=Math.max(z1,z);
        System.out.print("2nd max"+z2)
  }
```

above code is used to find second max number among 3 numbers using max and min function. is there any shortcut code to find that without if else or ternary operator only by using max and min function.

Comment: It seems like your are only interested in a completely mathematical max/min only solution. In that case you should **clearly state so** in your question. You can see at the current answers that most try to help you by showing you some neat functions of the Java API instead of posting a pure mathematical expression like @nagendra547 did, because you did not clearly express what you want.

Comment: yeah sorry for it

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution to get 2nd max.

```
a+b+c - Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c)- Math.min(Math.min(a,b),c)
```

---

We want to find the element in the middle. Therefore we find the maximum and minimum of all three values:

```
int maximum = Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c)
int minimum = Math.min(Math.min(a,b),c)
```

We can now get the element in the middle, the missing element, by finding the difference between all elements and the minimum and maximum.

```
int allElements = a + b + c;
int minAndMax = maximum + minimum;
int difference = allElements - minAndMax
```

The `difference` is now the element in the middle, the second maximum.

Comment: @Zabuza Because a+b+c is the sum. The first term max of max is the max of all three. the second term is min of min which is the min of all three. So sum of all three minus the max and the min must equal the middle value!

Comment: @abhishekdutta If you think, my reply answered your question, you can accept it. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the elements in an array and then sort the array. In your case something like:

```
Integer[] array = {a,b,c};
Arrays.sort(array);
return array[array.length-2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the maximum, remove it and then find it again. This approach has the advantage that it also works for arbitrary many inputs.

```
void cal(int a, int b, int c) {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(3);
    values.add(a);
    values.add(b);
    values.add(c);

    Integer maxValue = Collections.max(values);
    // Remove object, not index
    values.remove(maxValue);

    int secondMax = Collections.max(values);
    System.out.print("2nd max" + secondMax)
}
```

---

Or in the case for **just 3 elements** you could simply **sort it** (like @panagdu suggests). It does **not add an overhead** because after finding the second maximum number you already know the **complete order** for 3 elements.

```
void cal(int a, int b, int c) {
    int[] values = new int[] {a, b, c};

    // Sorts in-place using efficient sorting algorithms
    Arrays.sort(values);

    // The first element is now the smallest, the last the biggest,
    // we take the element in the middle
    System.out.print("2nd max" + values[1]);
}
```

---

With Java 8 you can also use `Stream`, they have the advantage that they can easily be executed in parallel. But I doubt that this would help for sorting 3 elements... anyway, here is a snippet:

```
void cal(int a, int b, int c) {
    int value = IntStream.of(a, b, c).sorted().toArray()[1];

    System.out.print("2nd max" + value);
}
```

Comment: no array no loop no if else nothing only max and min function

Answer (score 0):

You could identify in a first stream processing the max value and in a second stream processing the second max value by filtering the first one :

```
void cal(int a,int b,int c){

  final int[] values = new int[]{a, b,c};

   int max = Arrays.stream(values)
    .max().getAsInt();

   int secondMax = Arrays.stream(values)
        .filter(i -> i < max).max().getAsInt();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note that Java API `Math.max` the method also uses `if` check to find the max value.

You can stream the three `int` values to sort and find the 2nd max value as shown below:

```
void cal(int a, int b, int c) {
    int secondMax = Arrays.asList(a, b, c).stream().
                      sorted().mapToInt(num -> num).toArray()[1];
    System.out.println(secondMax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `List` and remove the max and min values.

```
static int secondGreatestNumber(int a, int b, int c)
{
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
    numbers.add(a);
    numbers.add(b);
    numbers.add(c);


    numbers.remove(new Integer(Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c))));//remove max value
    numbers.remove(new Integer(Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c))));//remove min value

    return numbers.get(0);
}
```